# keep linebreaks from multiline textfield in certain sections

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I want to provide a method that breaks up the contents of a multiline text field and allows line breaks to be preserved for certain sections. For example, the input looks like this:

```
title1: 11.11.2021
title2: documentation
title3: right
Comment: Here 
I still have no 
idea how to keep the 
line breaks

title4: something
```

I want to keep the whole thing in a data structure(key/value) and output it in the order as requested by the end user. The key would be e.g. "title1" and the value "11.11.2021". For comment the value should be the text with line breaks "Here I still....". Unfortunately I have no influence on how the data is written into the multiline text field. It can also happen that another field Comment is added. Of course I am also open for other data structures

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse line by line, check if a Key:Value situation is found. Remember the key. If no Key:Value is found and you got a key, extend the last keys value:

```
string t = @"title1: 11.11.2021
title2: documentation
title3: right
Comment: Here 
I still have no 
idea how to keep the 
line breaks

title4: something";

var d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
string key = null;

foreach (var line in t.Replace("\r\n","\n").Split ('\n'))
{
  var kvp = line.Split (":".ToCharArray (), 2);

  if (kvp.Length == 1 && key == null)
    throw new Exception ("First line has no key!");

  if (kvp.Length == 1)
  {
    d[key] += $"\r\n{line}";
    continue;
  }

  if (kvp.Length == 2)
  {
    key = kvp [0];
    d [key] = kvp [1];          
  }
}

foreach(var kvp in d)
  Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} = '{kvp.Value}'");
```

Output:

```
title1 = ' 11.11.2021'
title2 = ' documentation'
title3 = ' right'
Comment = ' Here
I still have no
idea how to keep the
line breaks
'
title4 = ' something'
```

Comment: Hello Patrick thank you that is a great solution. Now I am only missing the solution for the problem that a key can occur twice. You could check the dictionary for key contains but unfortunately the value for the key is already overwritten in the dictionary. I would have to rename the key when filling the dictionary e.g. comment, comment1, comment2 etc.. Would you have a suggestion for me?

Many thanks and greetings

Comment: @Tim - you can do that inside `if (kvp.Length == 2):` .. before inserting a new Key:Value check if key already exists. If so, modify it with a number or timestamp or smth alike. Happy coding.